# React Native TextInput onPressOut fires instantly

Tags: react-native

I am making a class for a custom TextInput, where the style will change when the field is selected, and will change back as soon as it is pressed out of. It looks as follows...

```
export function SoftSearchBar({
    height=40, 
    width='100%', 
    fontSize=20,
    fireOnChange={function(){console.log("No Change Function in place")}},
    value=false,
    placeholder="Placeholder",
    type=null
}){
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false)
    const [style, setStyle] = useState({})

   useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isActive)
        if (isActive){
            setStyle(style => ({style: styles.softSearchActive, width: width}))
        }
        else{
            setStyle(style => ({style: styles.softSearchInactive, width: width}))
        }
    }, [isActive])


    return(
        <View style={{height: height, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TextInput
                value={value}
                onPressIn={() => setActive(true)}
                onPressOut={() => setActive(false)}
                style={{...style.style, width: width, zIndex: 0, fontSize: fontSize}}
                textContentType={type}
                text
                placeholder={placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor={'black'}
                autoCorrect={false}
                onChangeText={text => {
                    fireOnChange(text)
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Almost all of this works as expected, when the field is pressed, an outline appears indicating its selection, and the text changes color. However, `onPressOut` fires immediately after `onPressIn`, as the log will look like this as soon as I press the field

```
true
false
```

indicating that `onPressOut` fired, since it is the only way to `setIsActive(false)`

I saw some solutions recommending using `onResponderRelease` as opposed to `onPressOut` but then it just never unselects. Is there some syntax Im missing with `onPressOut`? This seems like a pretty simple and straightforward syntax so I am unsure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Issue with your code is `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` you need to change them to `onFocus` and `onBlur`

Here is a working example you can paste into this website

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

You can set your default Input style and then when active you can enable the style you want.

`outlineStyle: none` to get rid of the default blue outline of the textinput when focused

Can also just remove `handleFocus & handleBlur` and move the function into the actual function calls to reduce the code further

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = React.useState({borderWidth:2 , borderColor: 'red', outlineStyle: 'none'});
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false)

 const handleFocus = () => setActive(true)

 const handleBlur = () => setActive(false)
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
style={[styles.input, active && style]}
         onFocus={handleFocus}
         onBlur={handleBlur}
        onChangeText={() => {}}
        value={null}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default UselessTextInput;
```